# "TV drama" vs. "TV series"

Tags: meaning

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drama)

> She's starred in several **TV dramas**

[TV series](https://www.yourdictionary.com/tv-series)

> A group of episodes of a television program broadcast in regular intervals with a long break between each group, usually with one year between the beginning of each.

[TV dramas](https://www.slideshare.net/BethanyTweddell/tv-drama-15031918#:~:text=So%20what%20is%20it%3F,over%20a%20number%20of%20episodes.)

> A TV drama is a show that runs in a series; it usually has a conclusion at the end ofan episode then moves on.

I guess "TV dramas" and "TV series" pretty much mean the same thing. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: There are lots of single-episode dramas, too, so the terms aren't entirely synonymous.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. Does "single-episode dramas" refer to [TV Movies](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052921505/)?

Comment: In the US, there's usually a distinction between "TV dramas" (usually one hour per episode and meant to be serious) and "TV comedies" (usually half an hour and meant to be funny). Both of these are "TV series."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you. Is [House of Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Cards_(American_TV_series)) an example of "TV dramas"?

Comment: @PutBere Yes, if the movies are dramas. Some may be comedies, some documentaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms do not mean the same thing.

### Drama is a genre

A drama is a work of fiction, usually with a serious tone. *Breaking Bad* and *The Sopranos* were dramas. *Friends* was not a drama, it was a sitcom. *Jeopardy* is not a drama, it is a game show.

### Series is a format

And the word has different meanings in American and British English. In American English, the word series is more or less synonymous with "show"; it refers to all of the episodes over the run of the show. In British English, the word series refers to a group of episodes that were released close together. In American English we use the word "season" for the same thing. Either way, a series is made up of many episodes as opposed to being a single stand-alone piece.

A drama is not necessarily a series: as commenters have pointed out, a TV movie could be a drama. And a series is not necessarily a drama because other kinds of shows are released as a series as well.